# Register window even listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I dynamically register window event listener (let's say on button click register focus event listener) on page, then will it available across other tabs (considering same page is open on multiple tabs)?

Comment: did you try it ? do you have sample code ?

Comment: event is register to dom/window. Creating a new tab/window creates a new window/dom hence it will in no way propogate to other tabs.

Comment: @AtulNar I tried it but no good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Different tabs have different window objects.  They are completely isolated.

This is for security, as one tab should not be able to eavesdrop on another tabs events.

To implement this behavior, you can listen to events on one tab, then send a `message` to the other tab.  This works because both tabs have agreed to communicate.

So in conclusion, one *tab can listen to "window events sent as messages* from another tab".